# Changing lisoffigures color in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using `Rmarkdown` with Rstudio to create PDF, and I add the option 
`\listoffigures`, but the font color of the links are pink.

I tried to add some TeX option to change it like `\listoffigures{"color_option"}`
but it doesn't work.

Does anybody have a solution ?

**Edit:**

I tried some new option I found in the LaTex Companion and it works!

I put the solution here if someone have the same issues.

```
\bgroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\listoffigures
\egroup
```

Comment: are you using sweave or knitr? I am guessing sweave, if so please include that in your orginial post

Comment: I'm using Knitr for sure. But i'm moving in the next week for sweave.